# Getting child data when clicking parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have currently got 4 separate divs, all containing different text within them. At the minute i can retrieve which box was clicked through jQuery, however i want to be able to return the text that is within it (title, address, distance).

Could anyone help me out with this?

Also it would be a even better help if someone could assist me getting this data from a JS object or JSON rather than it being hard coded (sorry i am just a bit unfamiliar with how it all works)

Thank you in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Currently gets the box ID 
  $(".address-box").click(function() {
    alert("You are clicking " + $(this).attr('id'));
  });


});
```

```css
.address-box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.address-box-number {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.address-data {
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.address {
  font-size: 17px;
  &__name {
    p {
      font-weight: 600;
    }
  }
  &__location {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
}

.address-distance {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="Square1 address-box" id="box-1">
  <div class="address-box-number">1</div>
  <div class="address-data">
    <div class="address address__name">
      <span id="box-1-title">some text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="address address__location">
      <span id="box-1-title">more text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="address-distance">
      <p>000 miles away (00 hour, 00min)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Square2 address-box" id="box-2">
  <div class="address-box-number">2</div>
  <div class="address-data">
    <div class="address address__name">
      <p>CARL ROSNER MOTORCYCLES</p>
    </div>
    <div class="address address__location">
      <p>249 London Road, Romford, Essex, RM7 9NB</p>
    </div>
    <div class="address-distance">
      <p>000 miles away (00 hour, 00min)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Square3 address-box" id="box-3">
  <div class="address-box-number">3</div>
  <div class="address-data">
    <div class="address address__name">
      <p>JACK LILLEY ROMFORD</p>
    </div>
    <div class="address address__location">
      <p>59 - 61 Albert Embankment, Vauxhall, London UK, SE1 7TP</p>
    </div>
    <div class="address-distance">
      <p>000 miles away (00 hour, 00min)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Square4 address-box" id="box-4">
  <div class="address-box-number">4</div>
  <div class="address-data">
    <div class="address address__name">
      <p>JACK LILLEY ASHFORD</p>
    </div>
    <div class="address address__location">
      <p>249 London Road, Romford, Essex, RM7 9NB</p>
    </div>
    <div class="address-distance">
      <p>000 miles away (00 hour, 00min)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: What i currently have on my page]

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: IDs need to be unique:  **id="box-1-title"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it. Instead of grabbing the ID, just use `children` and `text` methods. I'd make an object variable and fill it with the different parts of the data from each div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".address-box").click(function() {
    var box = {};

    // get all the nested children
    var children = $(this).children('.address-data').children()

    // iterate through each and make an associative array with the text
    $.each(children, function(value) {
        var className = $(this).attr('class');
        box[className] = $(this).text();
    });

    // do whatever you want with the box data
    console.log(box);
  });


});
```

EDIT: updated to iterate through children and populate object

https://jsfiddle.net/bd0dd3jt/14/

Comment: Thank you very much Kirill, it works as expected! 

Do you have any idea on how i would retrieve this data through a JS object so it isn't hardcoded? Thank you again for your reply :)

Comment: Updated to make it an object. Give me a second, I'll make it a bit nicer for you.

Comment: you may avoid children and you need to add text in order to remove unwanted chars:  **box.address = $(this).find('.address.address__name').text().trim();**

Comment: @Mark check out the updated version. This is how you can make it dynamic.

Comment: Wow thank you very much Kirill you've really helped me out here i can't thank you enough buddy!

Do you think it's still possible to get the data in a object rather than hard-coded in the HTML, as what i am trying to achieve is you use the google maps API which finds the nearest dealers to the postcode you have entered (just needs to be dummy data) I will attach an image with what i have currently got - sorry i had to trim it down for less confusion :P

Comment: No problem. Would you mind marking this as answered? I think you're talking about dynamically generating your HTML from the API data. What back-end language are you using? You should be able to iterate through the API object and dynamically create these divs. Might be a separate question though :)

Comment: updated an image now @Kirill, hope that makes it clearer to why i need the data to be in an object :) - Thanks!!

Comment: I am not using any back end, purely front end, is this still possible?

Comment: It's possible, but it can get quite messy without a framework. You can use jQuery's `html()` or `append()` methods to populate a div. So, for each place from the API, you can do something like this: `$('body').append('<div class="Square"><div class="address_name"><p>' + apiAddress.name + '</p></div></div>');` Where you iterate through the API response, and `apiAddress` is the value inside foreach loop. Kind of hard to explain in a comment. Make a separate question if this is unclear.

Comment: I think it has to be dynamic due to the data that will need populating from google maps, thank you very much for your help @KirillSimin

Comment: @Mark You got it. If you don't mind, would you mark this one as correct answer. That'd help me out a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry @KirillSimin i didn't even know how to, done now! Thank you very much for your help yesterday :)

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1

create  classes like ‘.box-title’ , ‘.box-address’ , ‘.box-distance’

```
<div class="Square1 address-box" id="box-1">
    <div class="address-box-number">1</div>
    <div class="address-data">
        <div class="address address__name">
            <p id="box-1-title" class="box-title">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="address address__location">
            <p id="box-1-address" class="box-address">more text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="address-distance">
            <p class="box-distance">000 miles away (00 hour, 00min)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Square2 address-box" id="box-2">
    <div class="address-box-number">2</div>
    <div class="address-data">
        <div class="address address__name">
            <p class="box-title">CARL ROSNER MOTORCYCLES</p>
        </div>
        <div class="address address__location">
            <p class="box-address">249 London Road, Romford, Essex, RM7 9NB</p>
        </div>
        <div class="address-distance">
            <p class="box-distance">000 miles away (00 hour, 00min)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Step 2:
 use find() to get the value and use array.push() to pass them to array

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var data = [];
    //Currently gets the box ID
            $(".address-box").click(function() {
                    data.push({
                        name: $(this).find('.box-title').text(),
                        address : $(this).find('.box-address').text(),
                        distance: $(this).find('.box-distance').text(),
                    });
                console.log(data);
            });


        });
```

Now you can convert this array to any possible format

**Edited:** update DOM dynamically using json data

you can use append() method to do that.

```
var data = [ // this array contains your data
            {
                name:
                address:
                distance:
            }
        ];
        var context='';
                for(let x=0;x<data.length ; x++){
                    context += '<div class="Square1 address-box" id="box-1">\n' +
                        '    <div class="address-box-number">1</div>\n' +
                        '    <div class="address-data">\n' +
                        '        <div class="address address__name">\n' +
                        '            <p id="box-1-title" class="box-title">' +
                        data[x]['name'] +
                        '</p>\n </div>\n' +
                        '        <div class="address address__location">\n' +
                        '            <p id="box-1-address" class="box-address">' +
                        data[x]['address'] +
                        '</p>\n </div>\n' +
                        '        <div class="address-distance">\n' +
                        '            <p class="box-distance">' +
                        data[x]['distance'] +
                        '</p>\n </div>\n' +
                        '    </div>\n' +
                        '</div>'
                }

                $('#context').append(context);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply buddy, would it be best practice to hard-code the text in HTML? I thought if you could use an object you could put something like 

dealerships.name[0] for the first instance of the array?

{
  "dealerships": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Dealership 1",
      "city": "Manchester",
      "region": "North West"
    },

then repeat this 4 times with different data?

Comment: Did you mean that add this data to your DOM dynamically?

Comment: if you meant that it's not good when you having huge data to show.see edited answer

Comment: Thank you for that my friend, if i am only displaying a maximum of 4 divs, is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

Question answered, had to target the child elements and adjust class names :)